# Problematic (logging) service discovery on rancher

Tags: docker, docker-compose, syslog, rancher

I want to send logs from one `rancher` service (e.g. `my_service`) to another `rancher` service running the `ELK` stack with the `syslog` driver

I am setting up my stack via a `docker-compose` as follows more or less:

```
 elk-custom:
    # image: elk-custom
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-elk
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
      - 9200:9200
      - 5044:5044
      - 5151:5151
      - 5152:5152


  my_service:
    image: some_image_from_my_local_registry
    depends_on:
      - elk-custom
    logging:
     driver: syslog
     options:
       syslog-address: "tcp://elk-custom:514"
```

However, on the stack dashboard, for `my_service` I get:

```
my_service (Expected state running but got error: Error response from daemon: failed to initialize logging driver: dial tcp: lookup elk-custom on 10.0.2.3:53: server misbehaving)
```

Is there anything additional needed to make the specific logging (`elk-custom`) service discoverable?

Comment: Assuming stack name as `ELK`, try `ELK.elk-custom` or `elk-custom.ELK`

Comment: you mean in the `syslog-address` field, e.g. `syslog-address: "tcp://ELK.elk-custom:5151"` ?

Comment: tried the above, now getting `no such host`

Comment: dont' know if this helps, but when I am using `syslog-address: "tcp://127.0.0.1:5151"` the message I get is `"127.0.0.1:5151: getsockopt: connection refused"`

Comment: No, it just means the localhost is something different. Check if rancher community can add some light on this.

Answer (score 1):

a few things are going on there that are problematic. First, if you are doing build, you have to use either a git or HTTP remote url or s3 based context.

Please see the docs: http://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v1.6/en/cattle/rancher-compose/#builds

Typically, you build an image and deploy it as a service. Builds are more of a development bit and less used on a production side of things.

The next thing is that in a multi-host setup, you will have trouble routing on the Rancher network. I would recommend deploying a Logstash collector on all nodes with the syslog ingress in host networking mode. Then you can point the logging driver to the localhost syslog target. Each of the logstash collectors would then forward to either another logstash for filtering or Elastic cluster.